# JavaScript FileReader API asynchronous - how to wait?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

i have implemented an Filereader with the FileReader API of JavaScript.
My problem is that I have to use it´s result, but since it´s asynchronous I can´t figure out how to get the data when it´s needed.

simplified:

```
function MyReader() {
reader = new FileReader();    
 this.myResult=[];
 //callback;

parse= function (evt) {
    switch (evt.target.readyState) {
        case FileReader.DONE:
            var result = evt.target.result;

             //parsing the file  and save into myResult     
            callback(myResult);
            break;
        case FileReader.LOADING:
            break;
        case FileReader.EMPTY:
            break;
    }
}}

  MyReader.prototype = {
             read: function (callback) {
              //callback=callback;
                var files = document.getElementById('files').files;    
              var file = files[0]; 
            reader.onloadend = parse; 
            var blob = file.slice(0, file.size);
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
},
   getResult: function () {
      alert(myResult.length);
   }};

  //index.html
 <script>reader = new MyReader();
         reader.read();
           //reader.read(function(res){alert("call: "+ res)});
           reader.getResult();
           alert("bla"); </script>
```

When I now run that I get first "bla" and then the length of the result.
But I need the result directly after I call read().
How can I ensure that the Reader is done when I need it? I already tried to introduce an "state" Variable and check that, but it didn´t worked. 
The only other idea I had was to use an callback with the function, which needs the result and add that to parse, but when I added a callback it doesn´t work and I don´t want to use an callback. Is it not possible to use some kind of mutexes? (Although it would be shit if the browser blocks....)

Comment: I think the reader uses an event. try reader.onload=function()...
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api

Comment: Yes, you have to use a callback, just like you are already doing for `parse`.

Comment: Seriously there is no other way? What should I do if I really need that data at time?     .......Can anyone tell me why it says that callback is not defined when I use it like that`?